# Finding the max value for each id, grouped by date

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to speed up cummulative sum within group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13081821/how-to-speed-up-cummulative-sum-within-group)

In the following data frame

```
id<-c(1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3)
spent<-c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90)
date<-c("11-11-07","11-11-07","23-11-07","12-12-08","17-12-08","11-11-07","23-11-07","23-       11-07","16-01-08")
df<-data.frame(id,date,spent)
df$date2<-as.Date(as.character(df$date), format = "%d-%m-%y")

  id     date spent      date2
1  1 11-11-07    10 2007-11-11
2  1 11-11-07    20 2007-11-11
3  1 23-11-07    30 2007-11-23
4  1 12-12-08    40 2008-12-12
5  1 17-12-08    50 2008-12-17
6  3 11-11-07    60 2007-11-11
7  3 23-11-07    70 2007-11-23
8  3 23-11-07    80 2007-11-23
9  3 16-01-08    90 2008-01-16
```

I need to find the maximum of `spent` for each `id` in each day and record in in a separate column as follow:

```
  id     date spent      date2   sum.spent
1  1 11-11-07    10 2007-11-11    20
2  1 11-11-07    20 2007-11-11    20 
3  1 23-11-07    30 2007-11-23    30
4  1 12-12-08    40 2008-12-12    40
5  1 17-12-08    50 2008-12-17    50
6  3 11-11-07    60 2007-11-11    60
7  3 23-11-07    70 2007-11-23    80
8  3 23-11-07    80 2007-11-23    80
9  3 16-01-08    90 2008-01-16    90
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You could just take the answers from [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13081821/567015) and replace `cumsum` with `max`. Basically these questions are exactly the same.

Comment: @SachaEpskamp, I hadn't seen that. I'm voting to close as a duplicate on this one considering that it is conceptually identical to the earlier question.

Comment: No need. It is a clearly stated question and already got an accepted answer.

Comment: There are a multitude of identical or near identical questions on SO. Definitely a duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your `plyr` answer:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(id, date), transform, sum.spent = max(spent))
```

This is the `data.table` answer (better for larger datasets):

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(df)
df[, sum.spent:=max(spent), by = list(id, date)]
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple approach using `ave()`:

```
df$sum.spent <- ave(df$spent, df$id, df$date2, FUN = max)
df
#   id     date spent      date2 sum.spent
# 1  1 11-11-07    10 2007-11-11        20
# 2  1 11-11-07    20 2007-11-11        20
# 3  1 23-11-07    30 2007-11-23        30
# 4  1 12-12-08    40 2008-12-12        40
# 5  1 17-12-08    50 2008-12-17        50
# 6  3 11-11-07    60 2007-11-11        60
# 7  3 23-11-07    70 2007-11-23        80
# 8  3 23-11-07    80 2007-11-23        80
# 9  3 16-01-08    90 2008-01-16        90
```

It's also simple using `data.table()`:

```
library(data.table)
# data.table 1.8.2  For help type: help("data.table")
dfDT <- data.table(df, key="id,date2")
dfDT[, sum.spent:=max(spent), by=key(dfDT)]
#    id     date spent      date2 sum.spent
# 1:  1 11-11-07    10 2007-11-11        20
# 2:  1 11-11-07    20 2007-11-11        20
# 3:  1 23-11-07    30 2007-11-23        30
# 4:  1 12-12-08    40 2008-12-12        40
# 5:  1 17-12-08    50 2008-12-17        50
# 6:  3 11-11-07    60 2007-11-11        60
# 7:  3 23-11-07    70 2007-11-23        80
# 8:  3 23-11-07    80 2007-11-23        80
# 9:  3 16-01-08    90 2008-01-16        90
```

Comment: I got a memory error since I have nearly 1.5 million rows.

Comment: @AliTamaddoni, Then try the `data.table()` solution I just posted.